# TypeScript Modules with classes in different files

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to split module to several files. I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436175/typescript-splitting-module-into-multiple-files) but with no luck, classes within same module but in different files seems to be unaccessible to me.

I'm using TypeScript 0.8.2 plugin for Visual Studio 2012

```
/* filesystem */
- /core
- - Router.ts
- - Server.ts
- /DefinitelyTyped
- - ..
- index.ts


/* file Router.ts */
///<reference path='../DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts'/>
import Url = module("url");

module Core {
    export class Router {
        static route(url: string) {
            var pathname: string = Url.parse(url).pathname;
            var query: string = Url.parse(url).query;
            console.log("About to route to " + pathname);
        }
    }
}

/* file Server.ts */
///<reference path='../DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts'/>
///<reference path="Router.ts"/>

import Http = module("http");

module Core {
    export class Server {

        private server: Http.Server;
        private port: number;

        constructor(port: number) {
            this.port = port;
            this.server = Http.createServer(this.onRequest);
            this.server.listen(this.port);
            console.log("Server started at http://127.0.0.1:" + this.port + "/.");
        }

        private onRequest(request: Http.ServerRequest, response: Http.ServerResponse) {
            var url: string = request.url;

            console.log("Received request: \"" + request.url + "\".");

            Router.route(url); //problem: Name 'Router' doesn't exist in this scope...

            response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
            response.write(url);
            response.end();
        }

        public getPort(): number {
            return this.port;
        }
    }
}
```

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, never mix and match `import`/`export` with `/// <reference>` tags to files that contain anything other than declarations (i.e. only reference `.d.ts` files if you use `import`/`export` anywhere in your code). What you want is this (see `NB` additions/deletions):

```
/* file Router.ts */
///<reference path='../DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts'/>
import Url = module("url");

// NB Removed containing module for clarity
export class Router {
    static route(url: string) {
        var pathname: string = Url.parse(url).pathname;
        var query: string = Url.parse(url).query;
        console.log("About to route to " + pathname);
    }
}

/* file Server.ts */
///<reference path='../DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts'/>
// NB Removed reference

import Http = module("http");
import Router = module("./Router"); // NB Added

module Core {
    export class Server {

        private server: Http.Server;
        private port: number;

        constructor(port: number) {
            this.port = port;
            this.server = Http.createServer(this.onRequest);
            this.server.listen(this.port);
            console.log("Server started at http://127.0.0.1:" + this.port + "/.");
        }

        private onRequest(request: Http.ServerRequest, response: Http.ServerResponse) {
            var url: string = request.url;

            console.log("Received request: \"" + request.url + "\".");

             // NB first 'Router' is the import name at the top of this file, feel free to change
             // NB second'Router' is the name of the class from that module
            Router.Router.route(url);

            response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
            response.write(url);
            response.end();
        }

        public getPort(): number {
            return this.port;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So packaging similar to Java is not possible?

Comment: I don't get it. `Router.Router` is so ugly. Besides, what @blootoon is originally doing is what it seems is in the tutorial for separate files [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-splitting-across-files)